# Is half-orc and half-elf a possiblity?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, half-elf, half-orc

I'm involved in a home brew where my DM has allowed me to play as a combination of half-orc and half-elf. My character has the stats of a half-orc that simply has a slightly increased lifespan and some cosmetics of an elf, but that is entirely irrelevant to my question.

I write expanded backstories for a few characters that I've played for the sheer joy of writing but I'd like to keep things as lore-accurate as possible for these tales. I understand that an orc's genes are dominate in the child resulting in it simply being considered a Half-Orc for PC creation. However, this is just a story I'm writing outside of the game.

I've had people tell me to look back at the 1e monster manual (which I do not have) to see that orcs and elves cannot mate, but I wonder if this is just for the sake of preventing PCs being made as such.

**In the general lore from any edition (i.e. setting neutral), can a male orc impregnate a female elf, or is there some genetic reason that an elf simply cannot birth the child of an orc?**

Again, I don't need anyone to tell me that as a PC, this is not a thing. I just want to understand the lore of these races as such.

Comment: Have you thought about a half-elf and orc breeding?

Answer (score 11):

### Traditionally no, but it may be possible, if rare.

According to AD&D-era lore, elves cannot breed with orcs at all. In *Dragon* magazine #60 (April 1982), the article "The Half-Elven Point of View" states:

> Elves and orcs cannot interbreed, which is interesting since both races can breed with humanity.

*The Complete Book of Elves* (1992), p.20, says that it is rare for an elf to successfully reproduce with anything but a human:

> Although there are rare exceptions, half-elves are also predominantly half human; elven genes typically cross with anything other than human genes.

The D&D 3e *Races of Faerûn* (2001), p.67, says that half-orcs carring some elvish blood might exist, but they may be a myth:

> Half-orcs are invariably the product of a human and an orc, but stories are told of half-orcs carrying the blood of dwarves, goblins, hobgoblins, and even halflings, gnomes, and elves. Orcs are a fecund race, and such storeis likely have some genesis in truth.

D&D 5e's *Monster Manual* (2014), p. 245, "Orc Crossbreeds", states definitively that orcs can reproduce with non-orc humanoids of similar size, though it doesn't say anything particularly for or against elves here:

> When an orc procreates with a non-orc humanoid of similar size and stature (such as a human or a dwarf), the resulting child is either an orc or a half-orc.

There is such a thing as the "blessing of Luthic" described in the D&D 5e *Volo's Guide to Monsters*, but it extends an orc's lifespan, rather than allowing them to interbreed with elves in particular. In fact, according to the 3e *Faiths & Pantheons* p.150, Luthic hates the elven gods as traditional enemies of the orcs.

Comment: Aside from the vague hints to abstract denials listed here, the only time an elf/orc crossbreed has ever appeared in anything remotely "official" for D&D is in the third-party setting Kingdoms of Kalamar for edition 3.0. There, the Tel-amhothlan is an elf/orc crossbreed normally produced by breeding male elves to female orcs. Mechanically, they're half-orcs that swap their Str bonus for a Dex bonus and downgrade Darkvision to Low-Light Vision, but get a +1 to saves vs. Enchantment spells and a +1 bonus to Listen/Spot/Search checks.

Answer (score -4):

Well it looks like I found an answer on Reddit in [a comment by the user Jimmicky on /r/DnD](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/ffooqx/halforc_and_halfelf_possible_nonpc_no_stats_needed/fjzqaga/):

> In old school lore a male Orc can impregnate any female human or Demi-human (including elves)
>
> This is the blessing of Luthic.
>
> As of 3e humans and Demi-humans are mixed in with humanoids (technically humans only became humanoid in 3.5)
>
> 1e and 2e didn’t extend Luthik’s blessing to humanoids, but it was a broader category back then.
>
> If you wanted to be beholden to the old lore (and you don’t need to be) it’d just be humanoids of the same rough limb structure and within X size of an orc (so nothing with tails or wings or more than 2 legs). That should get you pretty close to the old fertility blessing

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, are you happy with this answer or are you looking for other users to post other answers?

Comment: Usually we expect sources a bit more solid than random comment by a random user. He may be right, but it would be worth to trace it back to a source book, Dragon Magazine issue, etc.